Accessing .sas7bcat file?
I've got a .sas7bcat file (with no corresponding .sas7bdat file). How do I open this in SAS?
Part of the issue is that, according to the error message, it was created for a different operating system.
Is this solvable? Either in SAS, or in R or Python or another language.

Was this a catalog file created on Linux that you're trying to open in Windows and vis-versa? Usually this is an encoding issue. SAS can deal with this with datasets but I don't think it can with catalogs, so switching to the right encoding (probably UTF-8 or WLATIN1 depending on where you're trying to open it) is the best method.

@stu-sztukowski I don't have information regarding which operating system it was created on. I'm trying to open it in SAS Studio.

How was this file given to you? Did you upload it to SAS Studio? Which version of SAS Studio are you using?

I received a zip of catalog files on email, which I then extracted on WIndows and uploaded to sas studio.  I'm using SAS OnDemand For Academics.

Got it. Take a look at this article. The person who sent you the zip of catalogs will need to send them to you as a transport file rather than catalogs: https://support.sas.com/kb/44/047.html

Thank you so much! Appreciate your help.

SAS catalogs do not transfer nicely between operating systems unlike SAS datasets, which tend to be a bit more robust if you are not using user-defined formats. The safest way to transfer catalog files from one person to another if the environments may differ is by converting them to a transport file.

SAS® Format catalogs are machine-dependent ... This error can also occur when you double-click on a data set to view it and the variables are associated with permanent user-defined formats. To view the formatted values, you must convert the format catalog for use in the new operating environment.

https://support.sas.com/kb/44/047.html
